Select a specific range for extracted points from a plot into an Excel file
I use Cases in order to extract points from a plot.
pointsp = Cases[plot2, Line[{x__}] :> x, All];

Then I export the points into an Excel file.
Export["data.csv", pointsp // Prepend[{"x", "y"}]]

The problem is I have as an input 51 points and those are the points that I need the data to be extracted for, but the Excel file gives me 78 points and none of them are the points that I need.
So is there a way that I can identify the specific points that I want the data for?
"post edit"
i fit the original data which is a specific number of points (51) points to an ODE using the order "Find fitt" then i draw the fitted model using the order as follows
model[e_, f_?NumberQ] := 
  model[e, f] = 
   First[S /. 
 NDSolve[{S'[t] == e*(S[t])^(2/3) - (f*(S[t])), 
   S[1971] == Y0}, {S}, {t, 1971, 2021}]];

fit = FindFit[Data, model[e, f][t], {{e, 0.01}, {f, 0.01}}, t, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 1,
   AccuracyGoal -> 1];

Print["Estimation Results: ", fit]

plot2 = Plot[{model[e, f][t] /. fit}, {t, 1971, 2021}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"logistic"}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thick}}, ImageSize -> {Large}, 
   AxesLabel -> {Style["(year)", Bold, Black], 
     Style["TJ*10^6", Bold, Black, Medium]}, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold], Background -> White, 
   AxesStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Black, Thick}}];

the points i want to extract are the points of the fitted model itself not the original
when i extract them as shown previously the excel file gives me 78 points that are different from the 51 points i used as an input

Could you provide more details? Like what data and command did you use to create plot2? How this data compares to what you get in excel; and why are you extracting data from the plot instead of using the original data?

thanks for your reply and i am sorry i am late for response
post edited

I still cannot run your code (Data is missing), but I now see what you are trying to do. Please refer to this question: How to obtain adaptive sampling as in Plot function?

thanks a lot for your help sir wish you all the best
